# How to create this textField with corner-radius in ios using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a textField like below

[image: Expected output]

How can I do that using swift ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this 
Swift :

```
let maskPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.textField.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.TopLeft, .TopRight]), cornerRadii: CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0))
    let maskLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    maskLayer.frame = self.textField.bounds
    maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
    self.textField.layer.mask = maskLayer
    let borderLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    borderLayer.frame = self.textField.bounds
    borderLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath
    borderLayer.lineWidth = 4.0
    borderLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
    borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clearColor().CGColor
    self.textField.layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
```

Obj-C

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.textField.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.textField.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.textField.layer.mask = maskLayer;

CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.textField.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
borderLayer.lineWidth   = 4.0f;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
```

Comment: Oww, very very thanks :) 
one last question, How can I change the color of the left side only

Comment: 1st accept my answer  . i ll check and update to you

Comment: okey, I am waiting

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers  follow this link to accept my answer

Answer (score 2):

```
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: yourtextField.bounds, byRoundingCorners: [.TopRight, .TopLeft], cornerRadii : CGSizeMake(15.0, 15.0))

        let templayer = CAShapeLayer()
        templayer.path = path.CGPath
        yourtextField.layer.mask = maskLayer
```

This should work.

Comment: Thanks, but results: http://image.prntscr.com/image/0a9e80bb00524eeaa3305b40caef0f08.png

corner transparent

Comment: @semihh try to use, yourtextField.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: unfortunately it did not happen. still the same

Comment: Use fillColor property for templayer and give color reference.